# What is a suitable buffer for Python's struct module

Tags: python, binary, buffering

In Python I'm accessing a binary file by reading it into a string and then using `struct.unpack(...)`. Now I want to write to that string using `struct.pack_into(...)`, but I get the error *"Cannot use string as modifiable buffer"*. What would be a suitable buffer for use with the `struct` module?

Comment: Which version of python are you using? I've played with structs a bit but haven' seen that before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you aren't trying to pack it into a specific object, just use [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to return a string.

Otherwise, [`ctypes.create_string_buffer`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) is one way to obtain a mutable buffer.

Comment: The buffer is the memory for a simple virtual machine, so I need to pack into a specific object. The memory is small but copying 128-512k for a single memory access is not an option.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in another answer, `struct_pack` is probably all you need and should use.  However, objects of type [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) support the buffer protocol and can be modified:

```
>>> import array, struct
>>> a = array.array('c', ' ' * 1000)
>>> c = 'a'; i = 1
>>> struct.pack_into('ci', a, -0, c, i)
>>> a
array('c', 'a\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00  ...
```

The original buffer protocol was a bit of a hack primarily for C extensions.  It has been deprecated and replaced by a [new C-level buffer API and memoryview objects](http://docs.python.org/c-api/buffer.html) in Python 3 (and in the upcoming 2.7).

Answer (score -1):

Two possibilities leap immediately to mind:

- You can use the Python [stringio](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) module to make a read/write buffer with file semantics.
- You can use the Python [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module to get a buffer you can treat like a list, but which will contain just binary bytes.