# how to init binary buffer in python

Tags: python, binary, buffer, init

so, I read from DB binary field i.e. 'field1' to var Buf1, and then do something like:

```
unpack_from('I', Buf1, 0)
```

so, all is ok. but question is how can I ini Buf1 without going to DB? I can get value from DB manually and init my var statically, but how? in DB field 'field1' I see something like '0x7B0500000100000064000000B80100006'. and how can I init valid binary buffer from it?

Comment: Does 'DB' mean database?  Why are you trying to initialize a database?  Tables grow as needed when you add more records.  Why is your hex number 33 digits (they're almost always even)?  Are you trying to unpack a string into a number?

Comment: DB - database. I mean that I don`t want to use database in test. I want to init binary buffer statically in code without going to database. so, I can go to database manually and copy value there, (example of value noted above, but really value is longer) but how to init buffer by that value?

Answer (score 0):

Just use pack or `pack_into` it's the python's opposite of unpack_from.

See also [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732660/what-is-a-suitable-buffer-for-pythons-struct-module).

But you should elaborate on your question and give more sample code. The value you say you see from field is too large to read it into an integer. I wonder if you get the complete value.